# What's the difference between getBuyIntent() and launchPurchaseFlow() methods for in-app billing?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

[This one](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase) says that I shall use getBuyIntent() to start purchase flow, whereas [another one](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Purchase) tells me to use launchPurchaseFlow().

Which one should I use?

Comment: intresting.. both looks same to me. We use lauchPurchaseFlow() without any issue. Even example given with google-play-services on github uses launchPurchaseflow() https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing  , Hopefully someone can give exact reason of using first one

Comment: @AmodGokhale upvote it please so we can get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with in app-billing you have to use [IInAppBillingService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl#L113). First link is about this service API. The second link (training section) explains example with wrapper around IInAppBillingService, so [underneath](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/e19a6b4783313d51eff5111d4359ca75e1b3ec50/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java#L432) it also uses `getBuyIntent()`.